# What's the best way to embed a small chunk of javascript in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my application.html:

```
<body>
  <div class="bg-cover">
    <div class="background">
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
      <main>
        <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
          <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>">
            <script>Materialize.toast("<%= message %>", 5000, 'rounded <%= message_type %>', 'success')();</script>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        <%= yield %>
      </main><!--End of main-->
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div><!-- end of container main-->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if embedding this script directly into the application.html is best practice. Could anybody advise what the best practice should be? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's a bad practice to do that, you should go for unobtrusive javascript practice instead (http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/unobtrusive-javascript-important) any javascript code is written in a Javascript file not inside the view.

To achieve this in your case you can add a div with a certain class incase there's a message, pass any parameter that you'll need in your javascript via the `data` attributes

```
<div class="show-material-message" data-message="<%= message %>"></div>
```

Then in your javascript `application.js` for example listen for this div and fire the `Materialize.toast` when you want

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".show-material-message").each(function(){
    Materialize.toast($(this).data('message'), 5000....
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow... I really didn't think of that. I just knew there was something wrong with putting in scripts directly. Thanks Bigsolom.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it that way, but I would put it in a partial:

`layouts/_flash_message.html.erb`

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>">
    <script>Materialize.toast("<%= message %>", 5000, 'rounded <%= message_type %>', 'success')();</script>
  </div>
```

and include it like so:

```
<body>
  <div class="bg-cover">
    <div class="background">
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
      <main>
        <%= render "layouts/flash_message" %>
        <% end %>
        <%= yield %>
      </main><!--End of main-->
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div><!-- end of container main-->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh... I guess I could do that, too. I've been reading some articles and everyone kept emphasizing on using the rails assets pipeline instead of embedding scripts directly. 
That's why I was wondering if this is still professional. But thanks. I'd go ahead and create a partial right away.

Comment: Yeah, for most things you should. But this is a one liner for flashes so its not essential to use sprockets, but you could create a `_flash.js` and include it in `application.js`

Comment: Aha, that was my issue. Since its just a line, surely, I'd be forgiven if I just directly embed. Thanks Chase, for your time.