# How do I know my whole app is Rails Asset Pipeline Compliant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, asset-pipeline, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to figure out where my issue is for when I try to use aws cloudfront to render the rails assets.  Not sure if there is a tool that will determine if my whole app is rails asset pipeline compliant (whether it meets its standards, etc).  Any help would be appreciated, even helping me figure out how do I know for sure that my assets are coming from CloudFront and not from my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good tutorial to do that

https://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx3VS6Q2Q2K0LJR/Caching-the-Rails-Asset-Pipeline-with-Amazon-CloudFront

You can tell if serving your assets from cloudfront worked or not by viewing the page source of your production environment and see where are your css and js files served from, if it's working you'll find something like this

```
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="http://your-distribution-url.cloudfront.net/assets/application-bfe54945dee8eb9f51b20d52b93aa177.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Or if you configured a domain for your assets `cdn.myapp.com` for example you'll find that the assets are served from it

---------------- **Update** -----------------

Generally you want to organize your assets first before moving them on to a CDN, for the `img` tag it doesn't matter if you use `image_tag` or not what matters is the url of the image; if it's an asset image (that can be found in `app/assets/images` for example use the `asset_url` helper so that it is served through your asset pipeline (that doesn't apply to you application's images like user profile images).

Also in your CSS files when you use assets (background images for example) use the `asset-url` helper to get the image through asset pipeline.

Also it's a bad practice to add javascript into your views because you won't be able to server this javascript from your assets pipeline, try to have all your javascript in separate js or coffescript files and use the "Unobtrusive Javascript" practice (more about that in this answer [What's the best way to embed a small chunk of javascript in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947723/whats-the-best-way-to-embed-a-small-chunk-of-javascript-in-rails/31948599#31948599)).

Comment: I tried it and it actually messed up my production environment.  All the CSS and js was corrupted.  I have a feeling that my whole app isn't rails asset pipeline compliant ... I am using html "<img" tags and not the rails image_tag ... wonder if that has something to do with it. I also have javascript on html.erb files (index.html.erb , show.html.erb, etc).  Not sure if that matters as well.  Appreciate the insight.